# Routing trouble on Rails 3 (related to singular/plural)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, blogs, routes, plural

I've read around the resources on how routing in Rails 3 works, but am running into some difficulties.

In my app there are Blogs and my routes.rb contains:

```
  resources :blogs
  root :to => "home#index"
```

URLs containing 'blogs' are work fine.

However what I'd like to do is have 'blog' in the URLs. Specifically, */blog/:id* (for show) and */blog* (for index).

If I add the line:

```
match 'blog' => 'blogs#index'
```

Then /blog does show the index, however it breaks my blog edit form as the action URL changes from /blog/:id to /blog.:id

Any ideas on how to use blog instead of blogs, and also allow the blog index to be on /blog? I've tried quite a few things (like *resource :blog*, and also *resources :blogs, :as => 'blog'*) and not getting anywhere. Assuming there's a way to do this without manually defining each route for show, edit, destroy and index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need use the :path option

```
resources :blogs, :path => 'blog'
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `match` line, and change your `resouces` line to:

```
resources :blogs, :path => 'blog'
```

Check: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#translated-paths